# Sorting dictionary like array

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift2

I have an array like:

```
newArray = ["10102","12021","6748"]
```

and a dictionary:

```
d = ["12021": "Wouter", "6748": "Jorben", "10102": "Ilke"]
```

What I want is the dictionary sorted in the order of the array. So the dictionary should be:

```
d = ["10102": "Ilke", "12021": "Wouter", "6748":"Jorben"]
```

Do you get what I mean? Any help is appreciated guys! Thank you very much!

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, they can not be sorted. Take the time to study dictionaries and arrays. That said, tell us what are you trying to accomplish, why you think you need a sorted dictionary, and we may be able to help you.

Comment: Oh thanks man. I'll find a way to do what I want. It's a little bit too complicated to explain.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant sort your dictionary because dictionary stores its data in random order.

Comment: Well, not really random, rather in unspecified order.